# Unable to create table with foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is the table structure I am trying to create:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_like_dislike_blog_comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `blog_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `blog_comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_disliked` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_liked` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_created_by_foreign` (`created_by`),
  KEY `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_updated_by_foreign` (`updated_by`),
  KEY `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_blog_id_foreign` (`blog_id`),
  KEY `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_blog_comment_id_foreign` (`blog_comment_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_blog_comment_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`blog_comment_id`) REFERENCES `blog_comments` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_blog_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`blog_id`) REFERENCES `blogs` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_created_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_like_dislike_blog_comments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But this error I am getting:

> Can't create table `unityofhindu1`.`user_like_dislike_blog_comments`
> (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: A list of the Conditions and Restrictions necessary for successful creation of an FK can be found here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html If having checked all this and you still have problems please publish all referenced table definitions as text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure your foreign-candidate key column type and size must be same in both the tables.**